# Multiline regex matching, issue in negated lookahead (CLOSED)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have `markdown` like below:

````
# Heading!
* unorder list!
1. ordered list
*no it's not list
2.just normal text

``` 
block 
code 
python
```

#goodbye
````

And I want use regex to seperate it to `3 part`, first and last is normal text, second is code block

Like this (some newlines is dropped by stackoverflow) :

First:

```
# Heading!
* unorder list!
1. ordered list
*no it's not list
2.just normal text
```

Code block:

````
```
block
code
python
```
````

Last:

```
#goodbye
```

I have used

````
/^```(.|\n)+```$|^(.|\n)+(?!`)$/gm
````

in `javascript` but not working. Can't get the code block.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Try `s.split(/^(\`{3}[^]*?^\`{3})/m)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Amazing! Could you post a answer for accepting?

Comment: Ezio, posted...

Comment: Please consider accepting/upvoting the answer that worked for you/proved helpful to you.

Comment: sorry, I just awake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex to match 3 backticks at the start of the line and then any chars, as few as possible, up to the first line that starts with 3 backticks, and wrap the whole pattern with a capturing group to use in `split` so that the matched part also landed in the resulting array:

```
s.split(/^(`{3}[^]*?^`{3})/m)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of a line
- `` `{3} `` - 3 backticks
- `[^]*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `^` - start of a line
- `` `{3} `` - 3 backticks.

JS demo:

```js
const regex = /^(`{3}[^]*?^`{3})/m;
const str = `# Heading!
* unorder list!
1. ordered list
*no it's not list
2.just normal text

\`\`\` 
block 
code 
python
\`\`\`

#goodbye`;
console.log(str.split(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not split on ``` ?

````js
var str = `# Heading!
* unorder list!
1. ordered list
*no it's not list
2.just normal text

\`\`\` 
block 
code 
python
\`\`\`

#goodbye`;

out = str.split('```');
console.log(out);
````

Answer (score 0):

With the option 'm' your regex is executed line by line. You'll need to test with one quest and manage the line breaks.

Like it:
`(?:\s|\S)([\s\S]+.*)`

See: https://regex101.com/r/Re23vd/1